# Pros and Cons: Methods for Detrending Time Series Data

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stationarity, trend

My memory is fuzzy on the advantages and disadvantages of various methods for detrending time-series data. I'm looking for a succinct summary of why and when one should or should not use the following:

- Differenced data
- Log-differenced data
- Error term, after regressing on *only* a linear or polynomial time series (e.g., 0,1,2,3,...,t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Differenced data

**USE:** When the series resembles that of a random walk, taking first differences makes it stationary, so that it can be described as linear series representation of autoregressive or moving average terms.

**DO NOT USE:** When the series appears to randomly fluctuate around its mean.

#### Log-differenced

**USE:** Similar to simple differencing but applied when the variance in the series is assumed to depend on the level. Or when the series is an index.

**DO NOT USE:** When there's no such assumption or where the series is not strictly positive.

#### Error term

In classical time series decomposition you should proceed as follows:

1. Decide on whether taking logs of original series is reasonable
2. Decide on whether regression on time variable is reasonable
3. Decide on whether to take differences of the residuals